# Task List Template is not visible on Add an app

Tags: list, list-template

I have Saved a Task list template and then when I am trying to find an app after clicking on "Add an App", I am not able to find the App.

I have tried to use other template which is not a task list, but that is working good.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have custom System Master page?

Comment: Yes i have custom Master page

Comment: Did you got the answer? I am looking for same.

Answer (score 4):

Please ensure that the Team Collaboration Lists Feature  is activated for the site.

You may do so by following the below steps -

Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Under Site Actions section, pick Manage Site Features -> Search for Team Collaboration feature and finally activate it.

This should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the page `http://<site URL>/_layouts/15/create.aspx` and create your list.

Comment: I have the same issue as the OP.  Didn't work for me, but this was a great suggestion.  It shows options for all the same things the "Add an app" page showed me, though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change custom System Master page to oslo or seattle i.e. default Master page. After changing, go to 'Add an app" page and find your template. After creating a list using template, you can revert your System Master page to custom Master page.

Comment: I have set seattle as master page. But unfortunately template is not appearing. Also i have noticed that its happening only with the task content type. I have also tried with other content type. Its working fine