# Timeline / Gantt chart for Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, task-list, gantt-view

I want to create a timeline / gantt chart for tasks in Sharepoint Online.  I am coming from working in a SP 2013 environment, where there was a standard Task list which had a gantt functionality.
Does something exist for Sharepoint Online?

From what I have read this initially did not exist, yet I read a question on SPSE that said it has been introduced since mid-2022.  I'm finding it difficult to find a definitive guide on this or even whether it is definitely possible.

I know Planner exists but, as far as I am aware, it does not have a timeline / gantt functionality.

**Update**

I found a [link to a 'semi-gantt' chart which is made using JSON](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365/how-to-create-a-gantt-chart-view-in-microsoft-or-sharepoint/m-p/2469377), though it's not a proper one as it doesn't have the progress bar.  All is does show which months a project's Start - End Date cover.  It's of no use to me though. (In fact this also referenced in the link Ganesh has kindly given too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no native Gantt view available in SharePoint online modern experience like in tasks list in SharePoint server (or classic experience lists).

However, you can use JSON formatting to create Gantt view like structure in SharePoint online lists / Microsoft Lists.

Check below list formatting samples which might help you:

1. [Project Gantt Chart](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/view-samples/project-gantt-chart)

   [image]
2. [Yearly Gantt Chart](https://github.com/pnp/List-Formatting/tree/master/column-samples/generic-yearly-gantt-chart)

   [image]

Comment: Here's one more related solution (you may need to create a account & sign-in or pay some charges): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oW8hw8ZxgM

Comment: Thanks for providing some alternatives Ganesh.  I've found that in MS Teams an MS Project gantt chart can be displayed too, though this will only show on a Teams site but, annoyingly, not a Communications site.

Comment: I've eventually used your solution #1 Ganesh - works really well, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Further research - I've found that on one of my Modern Sharepoint Online sites I had to activate a site feature.  Please see [Amit's answer to this question here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/213941/task-list-template-is-not-visible-on-add-an-app#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20Site%20Actions%20%2D%3E%20Site,This%20should%20fix%20it.&text=Save%20this%20answer.,-Show%20activity%20on).

'Go to Site Actions -> Site Settings -> Under Site Actions section, pick Manage Site Features -> Search for Team Collaboration feature and finally activate it.'

This allowed me to create the old style (classic) Task list.

However, my aim was to add the Task list to a modern page in a web part.  This I am unable to do, as you see in the picture below, I have the option of adding a couple of lists, but not the classic list I want to use (my task list is called *Timeline (BA1)*).

Maybe this can be useful information for someone else, but for the page I'm trying to create I've hit a dead end.

[image: Picture of page in edit mode, it shows two options of available lists I can add, but does not show the classic Task list]

UPDATED 03/07/2023 - I've used Ganesh's suggestion, option #1, it works really well!  You can format the colours of the JSON code it uses too; I've posted other questions on this, should anyone else end up going down this path.